# Product states in quantum statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator

I'm a physical chemist so bear with me. We are going over quantum statistical mechanics, and to motivate and derive the density matrix, my advisor used the following explanation:

We have a system of interest in contact with it's surroundings. The system + surroundings are isolated, and are described by the state $|\Psi\rangle$. We can write this state as a product state
$$
|\Psi\rangle = |s\rangle|b\rangle
$$
where $|s\rangle$ is the state of the system and $|b\rangle$ is the state of the surroundings.
He then expands both the system and bath states in a basis which spans their separate spaces
$$
|s\rangle = \sum_i c_i|\phi_i\rangle
$$
$$
|b\rangle = \sum_i d_i|\theta_i\rangle
$$

Then expressing the total state as
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{i,j}c_{ij}|\phi_i\rangle|\theta_j\rangle
$$
He then used the partial trace over the bath states to generate the density matrix.

My question is about the product state. Is the fact that we can express the total state as a product of states of the system and bath guaranteed to be true, or is this some sort of postulate?

Second, what is the nature of this product state? The state of the system and the state of the bath exist on different Hilbert spaces, right? Is this a tensor product? I just now came across the tensor product postulate today while researching this question, but it appears to me that it states that the state of a composite system, such as the total (system + surroundings) here, are given by the tensor product of the two subsystems.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is one of the postulates. The state of the composite system is described by a tensor product of the component systems. So the Hilbert space of your system is the tensor product of the system and bath's Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{s}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{b}$. These types of states are called separable. However, for entangled two systems, the composite system cannot be described by a tensor product.

Comment: We need to distinguish two things. We often postulate that the Hilbert space has the tensor-product form ${\cal H}={\cal H}_s\otimes{\cal H}_b$. That's part of the definition of the model. In that context, a state-vector of the form $|\Psi\rangle=|s\rangle\otimes|b\rangle$ is called a product state, but most state-vectors in ${\cal H}_s\otimes{\cal H}_b$ are not product states. State-vectors that cannot be written as product states are called entangled. Even if the state-vector is initially a product state, the interaction between the two parts will generically cause it to become entangled.

Comment: So if the composite system is in an entangled state, is it still possible to use the last equation I gave (where we have a linear combination of product states), and therefore still define the density matrix in this way?